# WPF and Grouped data performance in .NET framework 4.5: Is there a test?

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, wpfdatagrid, .net-4.5

WPF Listbox or Datagrid exhibit very bad performance when data are grouped due to missing virtualization:

[WPF DataGrid Virtualization with Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477044/wpf-datagrid-virtualization-with-grouping)

Performance improvement is promised  in .NET framework 4.5. ([Improved performance when displaying large sets of grouped data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#grouped_virtualization)). Is it true? Does somebody tried it?

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Comment: The hidden programming qustion is should I use net 4.5 as soon as possible or it is useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box there is no performance improvement. It is necessary to set the attached property
[VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.isvirtualizingwhengrouping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (new in framework 4.5), which allows to switch on virtualization when grouping.

```
<DataGrid EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
   VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">
```

The perfomance gain is enormouse. Expanding of about a thousand member group went from about 40 seconds to a fraction of a sececond.