# WPF CollectionViewSource performance issues when changing flitering/grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

Hi I have a problem with the CollectionViewSource performance. I have a CollectionViewSource bound to a Datagrid. The underlying CollectionView object contains one group description. I also use a filter that I change quite often to filter the CollectionView. Each time I change the filter, GroupDescriptions get cleared automatically. If I try to add again my group description after I change the filter, the UI freezes for a few seconds which is quite annoying. Normally the CollectionView contains 200-1000 objects. What could I do to speed up performance?

Comment: is it wpf datagrid or some third party ?

Comment: it is a custom datagrid inheriting from WPF datagrid

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .net 4.5, enable grouping virtualization on the DataGrid:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
```

Comment: Our PCs are all in .NET 4.0. So I cannot use this unfortunately.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477044/wpf-datagrid-virtualization-with-grouping