# Is there a way to enable container recycling when grouping in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, listbox

I have a `ListBox` that can contain hundreds of items. I've added the following attributes to the listbox and performance is great, even if I group / ungroup (using x as `ListCollectionView`)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding x}"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
```

However, if I set the `ListBox.GroupStyle` to anything, even the most simple thing possible, it takes a few seconds to switch from grouped -> ungrouped.

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

I think the reason for this is that WPF is throwing away the cache of containers (enabled by recycling mode in the `VirtualizingStackPanel`) when I switch to ungrouped and is having to rebuild them from scratch.

Is there a way to improve the performance here? Can anyone suggest something I could try or perhaps a resource I could check out?

Comment: Looks like WFP 4.5 will get virtualization support for grouping: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#grouped_virtualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post, maybe it will be helpful

[WPF: Data Virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataVirtualization.aspx)

Also I found similar question on stackoverflow: [WPF ListView Virtualization Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102029/wpf-listview-virtualization-grouping)

and another one (even with answer) [WPF Data virtualizing ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981040/wpf-data-virtualizing-listview)